# how to make array_walk_recursive ignore for specific key values

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I want to make an `array_walk_recursive($my_array, 'myfunction');` but only if the key does not contain the string `_ignore`.

To make it more clear:

```
function Capitalize(&$input)
{
    $input = strtoupper($input);    
}

$my_array = array();    
$my_array[0]['title']="apply to this";
$my_array[0]['info']="apply to this also";
$my_array[0]['data_ignore']="don't touch this!!!!";
$my_array[1]['title']="you can change this";
$my_array[1]['info']="you can also change this";
$my_array[1]['data_ignore']="i said don't touch this! cant you see the key's name?";

array_walk_recursive($my_array, 'Capitalize');

// i wish the function to be applied to all elements except the ['data_ignore'] ones
```

p.s. of course my question is not about capitalization, im just providing an appropriate example.

p.s.2 what i tried: i couldnt find any way to pass the key to the function so i could program the bypass there :(

p.s.3 so my problem will be solved if you could answer the question "How to get key name from a referenced variable?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
function Capitalize(&$input,$key){
    if(strpos($key,"_ignore") ===FALSE ){
      $input = strtoupper($input);    
    }
}
```

See demo [here](https://eval.in/115849)

Comment: oh, how $key is passed?! (thank you! -ill accept answer when im able to -need to wait)

Comment: no need to pass it, the second argument is the key see more info http://in2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Comment: need to find a wall to bang my head. HARD. thank you again Mr Nouphal :) `Typically, callback takes on two parameters. The array parameter's value being the first, and the key/index second. `

Comment: @Sharky: It has happened to me too. I had to do something similar before, and I wrote a recursive function to accomplish instead. Only months later did I realize key can be accessed using the second parameter. It's always a good idea to read the documentation for the function! Cheers!